# Issue when Loading PHP Page and loading Sliders images

Tags: php, mysql

When my home page loads it does something weird and then loads the slider images.
This is what it looks like below when the page is first loaded, it does this to all of the images and then it puts it into a place where it should be, but it looks like this for few seconds. It has a black dot and then some white blank space next to it like shown below. Any ideas on why My code is causing this? I'm retrieving the images link from a MYSQL Database. Any Ideas on why it's doing this? Thank You In Advance.

[image: issue]

This is what it looks like after the few seconds.It's perfectly fine. 
[image: perfectly fine]

Heres my Code for the slider.

```
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM slider WHERE live="on"');
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        ?>
            <li data-index="rs-80" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500"
                data-saveperformance="on"
                data-title="Intro Slide">
                <img src="images/slider/<?php echo $row['link']; ?>" alt="slidebg1" 
                     data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover"
                     data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                <div class="revolution_heading_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="0"
                     data-y="200" data-speed="700" data-start="10" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="chars"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #FFFFFF;font-size:30pt;font-family: Montserrat">
                    <?php echo $row['slide_name']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="300" data-speed="300" data-start="600" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="words"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; line-height: 30pt; margin-left:8px">
                   <?php echo $row['slide_desc'];?> 
                </div>


                                        <?php
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
                                        <?php
}
?>

            </li>        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Orginal Slider code without any PHP in it.

```
<div class="tp-banner-container rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container"
     data-alias="news-hero72">
    <div class="tp-banner-slider">
        <ul>
            <li data-index="rs-80" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500"
                data-saveperformance="on"
                data-title="Intro Slide">
                <img src="images/dummy.png" alt="slidebg1" data-lazyload="images/thumbnails/home_bowl.png"
                     data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover"
                     data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                <div class="revolution_heading_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="0"
                     data-y="200" data-speed="700" data-start="10" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="chars"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #FFFFFF;font-size:30pt;font-family: Montserrat">
                    Get Some Fun
                </div>
                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="300" data-speed="300" data-start="600" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="words"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; line-height: 30pt; margin-left:8px">
                    A stones throw away from famous Coogee Beach,
                </div>
                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="370" data-speed="300" data-start="1800" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="words"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; margin-left:8px">
                    perfect place to spend time with family & friends.
                </div>


            </li>
            <li data-index="rs-81" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500"
                data-saveperformance="on"
                data-title="Intro Slide">
                <img src="images/dummy.png" alt="slidebg1" data-lazyload="images/thumbnails/home_image.png"
                     data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover"
                     data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                <div class="revolution_heading_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="0"
                     data-y="170" data-speed="700" data-start="10" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="chars"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #FFFFFF;font-size:30pt;font-family: Montserrat;">
                    Game that makes you crazy
                </div>

                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="270" data-speed="300" data-start="410" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="words"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; line-height: 30pt; margin-left:8px">
                    We offer huge discounts who come to have fun
                </div>
                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="340" data-speed="300" data-start="1800" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="words"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; margin-left:8px">
                     A chance to earn points in referal scheme.
                </div>

            </li>
            <li data-index="rs-82" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500"
                data-saveperformance="on"
                data-title="Intro Slide" class="home2_why">
                <img src="images/dummy.png" alt="slidebg1" data-lazyload="images/thumbnails/home_bowl1.png"
                     data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover"
                     data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">

                <div class="revolution_heading_font1 tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="0"
                     data-y="170" data-speed="700" data-start="10" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="chars"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #FFFFFF;font-size:30pt; font-family: Montserrat">
                    WHY PEOPLE COME TO HAVE FUN WITH US?
                </div>
                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="300" data-speed="300" data-start="600" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="lines"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; line-height: 30pt; margin-left:8px">
                    1. &nbsp;Lavishing Fun and Entertaintment Hub.
                </div>
                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="355" data-speed="300" data-start="1800" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="lines"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; line-height: 30pt; margin-left:8px">
                    2. &nbsp;Keeping your taste in mind, we provide the best.
                </div>
                <div class="revolution_font tp-caption grey_heavy_72 skewfromrightshort tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-2" data-x="5"
                     data-y="417" data-speed="300" data-start="2500" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="lines"
                     data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                     style="z-index: 5; max-width: inherit; max-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;color: #ffffff;font-weight: 300;font-size:18pt; margin-left:8px">
                    3. &nbsp;We just never let a gamer to wait in a queue.
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like simply the default formatting for a UL/LI list construct being applied ... before the formatting defined by the slider “takes over”. You might need to embed your slider’s CSS earlier or something like that ... Most likely not really a PHP issue to begin with, with a static HTML document containing the same code you’d likely have the exact same problem.

Comment: Your images are abit big (as you can see your only seeing the tip of that mountain), reduce size/quality to fit the biggest browser 2k ish and you wont even notice the load.